# Как сделать постоянную проверку на наличие обьекта на странице?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать постоянную проверку на наличие обьекта на странице, а не только ее загрузки?

if(!$('.div').length) - такой вариант не подходит, тк он проверяет страницу только когда она загрузилась.

А тот блок на который надо делать проверку появляется после нескольких кликов по странице (появляется путем добавление класс со стилем display:block;)

Comment: повесьте на конкретный элемент событие для его удаления и всё остальное время считайте, что элемент на странице (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19050656/javascript-on-element-removed-event-listener)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант вы можете запустить таймер и проверять есть у вас этот элемент или нет

```
setInterval(function(){
  if(!$('.div').length) {
    alert("Элемент пропал");
  }
}, 1000);
```

Вот, например, проверка каждую секунду.
Решение конечно не очень "красивое", но это именно то что вы хотели - постоянная проверка.

Хотя возможно вы не совсем правильно решаете свою задачу. И возможно она решается совсем по другому.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, спасибо. Поправил.

Comment: Спасибо за решение
Соглашусь, что решение задачи не совсем верное, может у вас есть другие варианты?
https://codepen.io/human_left/pen/XWYjbzR
Тут основная задача в том, чтобы сбрасывать первый фильтр если сделали выбор у второго фильтра

Comment: @human_left зачем вам отслеживать что-то. Вы же сами описали алгоритм. Когда делаете выбор во втором фильтре, делайте очистку в первом, и наоборот, если того требует условие

Comment: @newman отслеживать есть ли choose-item на странице и если есть делать отчистку